# How do you filter one to many relationships with fluent-NHibernate?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have a set of entities where they could possibly be set as deleted using an "IsDeleted" flag in the database.

This is fine for the normal set of entities, however when I have a parent with many child entities that may have this flag I would like NHibernate to be able to automatically handle selecting the child entities that have "IsDeleted" set to false.

Is there anyway to do this with fluent-NHibernate? Or the XML mappings that I could add view fluent.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not something that can be done in the mappings, Fluent NHibernate or standard XML. What you need to do is register a DeleteEvent listener. There's a post on the [NHibernate FAQ](https://web.archive.org/web/20110227204838/http://blogs.hibernatingrhinos.com/nhibernate/Default.aspx) on [Soft Deletes](https://web.archive.org/web/20090209010820/http://blogs.hibernatingrhinos.com/nhibernate/archive/2008/04/08/soft-deletes.aspx) that's very good.